# PyQt5 - Worker Runs Slower with More CPU Usage in QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread, qobject

I am making a PyQt5 real-time application that streamline images and its segmentation result on interface. It has 3 components as a cycle:

1. pull out frame
2. feed the frame into segmentation module
3. print out original frame and segmentation result on interface

In particularly, (2) is a bottleneck. I tried to run (2) in main thread, and compared its speed and CPU consumption rate against running (2) in background (using QThread). I strangely found that running by QThread costs ~20 ms slower and is more CPU intensive.

**Method 1: Wrapping (1), (2) in a QObject Worker and Run in Main Thread**

I don't intentionally want to run all these in main thread because it causes window being locked, but I do this for speed testing. Below is my implementation of the QObject worker (`FrameStore` is an object retrieving key results in QObject and pass them to GUI):

```
class FrameObject(QObject):
    frame_signal = pyqtSignal(FrameStore)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.load_img()
        self.IS_SILENT = True
        self.model_config = ModelMetaConfig()
        self.frame_store = FrameStore()

    def load_img(self):
        self.PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test_cases', 'test.jpg')
        rgb_img = cv2.imread(self.PATH)
        self.rgb_img = rgb_img[:, :, ::-1]

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        end_loop = time.time()
        while True:
            crt_t = time.time()
            print('time = {:10.4f} s'.format(time.time()))
            print('unexplain = {:10.4f} s'.format(crt_t - end_loop))
            torch.cuda.synchronize()
            start = time.time()
            seg_out = self.model_config.raw_predict(self.rgb_img, self.IS_SILENT)
            seg_out = self.model_config.process_predict(seg_out, self.IS_SILENT)
            torch.cuda.synchronize()
            end = time.time()
            print('model run = {:10.4f} s'.format(end - start))
            start = time.time()
            # store key data at a snapsho
            self.frame_store.rgb_img = self.rgb_img
            self.frame_store.seg_out = seg_out
            #self.frame_signal.emit(self.frame_store)
            end_loop = time.time()
            self.frame_signal.emit(self.frame_store)
            print('emit = {:10.4f} s'.format(end_loop - start))
```

Below screenshot tells that **CPU usage is 60% with frame rate ~120 ms**:

[Screenshot: ~60% CPU Usage + ~120 ms Frame Rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAYsO.jpg)

**Method 2: Wrapping (1), (2) in a QThread**

My implementation of QThread is similar to the QObject above:

```
class FrameThread(QThread):
    frame_signal = pyqtSignal(FrameStore)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.load_img()
        self.IS_SILENT = True
        self.model_config = ModelMetaConfig()
        self.frame_store = FrameStore()

    def load_img(self):
        self.PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test_cases', 'test.jpg')
        rgb_img = cv2.imread(self.PATH)
        self.rgb_img = rgb_img[:, :, ::-1]

    def run(self):
        end_loop = time.time()
        while True:
            crt_t = time.time()
            print('time = {:10.4f} s'.format(time.time()))
            print('unexplain = {:10.4f} s'.format(crt_t - end_loop))
            torch.cuda.synchronize()
            start = time.time()
            seg_out = self.model_config.raw_predict(self.rgb_img, self.IS_SILENT)
            seg_out = self.model_config.process_predict(seg_out, self.IS_SILENT)
            torch.cuda.synchronize()
            end = time.time()
            print('model run = {:10.4f} s'.format(end - start))
            start = time.time()
            # store key data at a snapsho
            self.frame_store.rgb_img = self.rgb_img
            self.frame_store.rgb2_img = self.rgb_img
            self.frame_store.rgb3_img = self.rgb_img
            self.frame_store.rgb4_img = self.rgb_img
            self.frame_store.seg_out = seg_out
            self.frame_signal.emit(self.frame_store)
            end_loop = time.time()
            print('emit = {:10.4f} s'.format(end_loop - start))
```

But it turns out the **frame rate is ~20-30 ms slower with 100% CPU usage**, as shown below:

[Screenshot: 100% CPU Usage + ~145 ms Frame Rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXzkD.jpg)

**Reproducing My Result**

I have uploaded a simplified version of my application on [my repo](https://github.com/riven314/pyqt_speed_test). You can reproduce my result by running `$ python main.py`. Note the application requires a GPU and installation of `pytorch`.
To switch between method 1 and method 2, just toggle comment in the following lines in `main.py`:

```
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # set up window
        self.title = 'Simply Reproducing the Slow Speed'
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 1280
        self.height = 1280
        self.init_window()
        #self.init_qobject() #<- uncomment this to run QObject in main thread
        #self.init_thread() #<- uncomment this to run QThread
```

A brief outline of key scripts:

1. `model_utils.py`: wrapping all segmentation procedures into a class
2. `object_utils.py`: a QObject worker class computing (1) and (2)
3. `thread_utils.py`: a QThread class computing (1) and (2)
4. `main.py`: main interface application

**Question**

The slow down and extra CPU usage is so annoying to me. Could anyone suggests me an alternative implementation that could delegate the work to background more efficiently?

Comment: Hey @alexwh i know its been a while since you posted this question, but here are my 2 cents on this.
case2: Since a new worker thread created context switching takes time which may be the reason for extra ms increment in time. And the reason maybe we are facing an increase in CPU usage could be because of the I/O based part from (1) is running parallel with (3) thus max cpu utilization!

I may be wrong not much of an expert myself, though now i'm in same state as u were back then. If you have insight how such applications can be improved to work fast please share !